# Two different maps of a cylinder into $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Suppose two maps from a cylinder into $\Bbb R^3$ :

$f : [0,1] \times S^1 \to \Bbb R^3 $ given by  $(t, \theta) \mapsto (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, t)$,

$g : [0,1] \times S^1 \to \Bbb R^3 $ given by $(t, \theta) \mapsto (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0)+$$ t\over{4} $$(\sin\theta \cos \theta, \sin\theta \sin \theta, \cos \theta) $.

What I want to show are the followings :

1. Is $g$ is an embedding?
2. Is there a homeomorphism $\phi$ of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $\phi ~\circ f=g $?

(I think this question is related to homotopy and covering space theory so I tagged these, but actually I'm not sure about this.) Any hints?

Comment: The formulae are not quite right, $\theta$ is from $[0,2\pi)$ presumably, not $S^1$? $(t,u) \to (u,t)$ seems more apt, abusing notation and considering $((\cos \theta, \sin \theta),t)$ the same as  $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta,t)$

Comment: $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$. You have $f(t,x,y) = (x,y,t)$ and $g(x,y,t) = (y + \frac{t}{4}xy, x + \frac{t}{4}x^2, \frac{t}{4}y)$.

Comment: Have you verified that $g$ is an embedding? It is not trivial.

Comment: Is the question still relevant?

Comment: @Elad I'm trying to solve this using your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but a visual hint that can help you solve the problem. Below the plot of $g$ (educated guess that $S^1$ is already parametrized ashenno mentioned in a comment).

[[image: This is a plot of your <span class=]$g$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7IUv.png)
The plot of $f$ is
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XDr5.png)
The hint is to look at the boundary of the surfaces and think of how they are linked.
The boundary of $g$ is
[image]
This is how the boundary of $f$ looks like:
[image] 
  (The boundaries are fattened so you can see them)